# js xml get another attribute of a known attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

If I know the attribute name, is there a better way, less intensive (I could have 100's os Swatches) way to write this? 
Something like: $("[attribute.name=='Clear-Matt']").$(this).attr('cost');

If there is not would this each function stop when (name=="Clear-Matt") or will it keep going to the end of the swatches? If so is there a way to stop it?

```
 var swatchCost='';
 $(xmldoc).find('Swatch').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      if (name=="Clear-Matt") {
           swatchCost=$(this).attr('cost');
      }   
 });
```

XML:

```
 <Swatch name="Clear" title="Clear" alt="Frame" cost="100" match=""></Swatch>
 <Swatch name="Clear-Matt" title="Clear-Matt" alt="Frame" cost="11" match=""></Swatch>
 <Swatch name="Blue-Orange" title="Blue-Orange" alt="Frame" cost="200" match=""></Swatch>
 <Swatch name="Pink-Blue-Clear" title="Pink-Blue-Clear" alt="Frame" cost="300" match="">   </Swatch>
 <Swatch name="Blue" title="Blue" alt="Frame" cost="11" match=""></Swatch>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way using the attribute selector.

```
$(xmlDoc).find('[name=Clear-Matt]').attr('cost'); // or use 'Swatch[name=Clear-Matt]'
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f447s/)**

And for your question of existing the for-each loop once you got what you need you can just do a `return false;` which is equivalent to `break;` statement.

```
  if (name=="Clear-Matt") {
       swatchCost=$(this).attr('cost');
      return false;  //break the iteration now.
  }
```